# Suppose the length of life of certain kind of light bulb, after it is installed, is exponentially distributed with a mean length of 7 days

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Suppose the length of life of certain kind of light bulb, after it is installed, is exponentially distributed with a mean length of 7 days. As soon as one bulb burns out, a similar one is installed in its place. Find the probability (correct to three decimal places) that more than 60 bulbs will be required during a one-year period?

Comment: How many days are supposed in one year?

Comment: 365 days in a year.